# How do you get the first existing ancestor directory given a file path?

Tags: perl, directory, filepath, file-exists

In Perl, if given a file path, how do you find the first existing ancestor?

For example:

- If given the path `/opt/var/DOES/NOT/EXIST/wtv/blarg.txt` and directory `/opt/var/DOES/` is not present but directory `/opt/var/` is, the result should be `/opt/var/`.
- If given the path `/home/leguri/images/nsfw/lena-full.jpg` and directory `/home/leguri/images/nsfw/` does not exist, but directory `/home/leguri/images/` does, the result should be `/home/leguri/images/`.

Is there a module or function which does this, or is it just a matter of splitting the path on `/` and testing for existence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest I know of is [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path%3a%3aClass), which doesn't do exactly what you want but may save you a couple of steps in splitting the path.

```
use Path::Class 'dir';

sub get_existing_dir {
    my ( $path ) = @_;

    my $dir = dir( $path );
    while (!-d $dir) {
        $dir = $dir->parent;
    }
    return $dir->stringify;
}

my $file = '/opt/var/DOES/NOT/EXIST/wtv/blarg.txt';
my $dir = get_existing_dir( $file );
print $dir;
```

Comment: the path begins with `/` : `/opt/var/DOES/NOT/EXIST/wtv/blarg.txt`

Comment: If you supply an entirely bogus relative path (`bogus/relative/path`), the method returns current working directory (`.`), which might or might not be what the OP wants. Also, at least on Windows, if `$path` uses a non-existent volume, the `while` loop fails to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Monkey patch it

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Class ;

my @paths = map dir($_) , 
    map join( '/', $_, 1..6 ),
    grep defined,
    @ENV{qw/ WINDIR PROGRAMFILES TEMP HOME /},
    'Q:/bogus/drive/and/path', 
    'QQ:/bogus/drive/bogusly/treated/as/file',
    ;
push @paths, dir('bogus/relative/path/becomes/dot');
push @paths, dir('bogus/relative/path/becomes/relative/to/cwd')->absolute;

for my $path ( @paths ) {
    print $path, "\n\t=> ", $path->real_parent, "\n\n";
}

sub Path::Class::Entity::real_parent {
    package Path::Class::Entity;
    my( $dir ) = @_;
    while( !-d $dir ){
        my $parent = $dir->parent;
        last if  $parent eq $dir ; # no infinite loop on bogus drive
        $dir = $parent;
    }
    return $dir if -d $dir;
    return;
}
__END__
C:\WINDOWS\1\2\3\4\5\6
    => C:\WINDOWS

C:\PROGRA~1\1\2\3\4\5\6
    => C:\PROGRA~1

C:\DOCUME~1\bogey\LOCALS~1\Temp\1\2\3\4\5\6
    => C:\DOCUME~1\bogey\LOCALS~1\Temp

C:\DOCUME~1\bogey\1\2\3\4\5\6
    => C:\DOCUME~1\bogey

Q:\bogus\drive\and\path\1\2\3\4\5\6
    => 

QQ:\bogus\drive\bogusly\treated\as\file\1\2\3\4\5\6
    => .

bogus\relative\path\becomes\dot
    => .

C:\temp\bogus\relative\path\becomes\relative\to\cwd
    => C:\temp
```

Comment: You could add that check to stevenl's answer without any problems. So why do want to take the risks of monkey-patching?